# Python PyQT5 how to get signals from QBasicTimer

Tags: python, timer, pyqt5

Sorry for that newbie Question, but i dont figure out where it is explained...

I am trying to Build a PyQt5 Gui and got stocked with a timer. In the web i see this alltimes:

```
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timerEvent)
```

But in PyQt5 the class QTimer is replaced with QBasicTimer and there is no timeout Method.

In another Tutorial i saw a Method called timerEvent what sends signals automatic, but for me it doesn get called -.- How to to that and where can i inform me byself?

thx

Comment: `QTimer` is not replaced with `QBasicTimer` in PyQt5. I don't know why you thought that. Just do `self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()`, and then `self.timer.setInterval(1000); self.timer.timeout.connect(self.slot); self.timer.start()`.

Comment: oh nice thank your that works! i dont know exactly what i got, but i tried to import QTimer from a wrong package and got a c++ message that said it has been removed... nvm... thx!